# How to disable tabs in UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbaritem, uitabcontroller

Before I updated to Swift 3, this worked perfectly (besides isEnabled was just enabled). This code is in my UITabBarController ViewDidLoad function. The `if` is never met so therefore the items are never set to true.

How do I access the items as I want the tabs to be greyed about until a variable is selected?

```
if  let arrayOfTabBarItems = self.tabBar.items as AnyObject as? NSArray,let tabBarItem = arrayOfTabBarItems[1] as? UITabBarItem {
    tabBarItem.isEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
let arrayOfTabBarItems = self.tabBar.items

if let barItems = arrayOfTabBarItems, barItems.count > 0 {
  let tabBarItem = barItems[0]
  tabBarItem.isEnabled = true
}
```